# How to notate if there is matching between column A and column B via a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, sql-like

I have query that results in a table as such:

```
ColumnX      ColumnY          
 apple     the apple is red   
 orange    orange tree is tall
 berry      the sky is blue
```

Basically want to create a new column that checks if ColumnX value is found in ColumnY represented as a "Yes" or "No":

```
 ColumnX      ColumnY               newColumn       
 apple     the apple is red            Yes
 orange    orange tree is tall         Yes
 berry      the sky is blue            No
```

I've tried something like:

```
case 
   when ColumnX like '%' + ColumnY + '%' then "Yes"
end as newColumn
```

To no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You want `like` operands  the other way around. Also, you should use single quotes to define string literals rather than double quotes.

So:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when columnY like '%' + columnX + '%'
        then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
    end newColumn
from mytable t
```

You can also use `charindex()`:

```
case when charindex(columnX, columnY) > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN ColY LIKE CONCAT('%', ColX, '%')
               THEN 'Yes'
               ELSE 'No'
          END NewColumnUsingLike,
          CASE WHEN PATINDEX(CONCAT('%', ColX, '%'), ColY) > 0
               THEN 'Yes'
               ELSE 'No'
          END NewColumnUsingPatIndex,
          CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(ColX, ColY) > 0
               THEN 'Yes'
               ELSE 'No'
          END NewColumnUsingCharIndex
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('apple',     'the apple is red'),   
  ('orange',    'orange tree is tall'),
  ('berry',     'the sky is blue')
) T(ColX, ColY);
```

[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=792cd6250276e58b7510f40eff28c236)